# How to convert this JSON string to equivalent list of class

Tags: android, json

I can parse the simple JSON string using the following code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            URL.toString() );




    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));

            finalResult.setText("Done") ;

            Result = reader.readLine();


        } else {
             Result = "error";
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         Result = "error";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Result = "error";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but now I have the following JSON string

```
[{"Name":"Ali" ,"Age":35,"Address":"cccccccccccc"} ,{"Name":"Ali1" ,"Age":351,"Address":"cccccccccccc1"} ,
{"Name":"Ali2" ,"Age":352,"Address":"cccccccccccc2"}
]
```

and class represent it

```
package com.appnetics;

import android.R.string;

public class Encounter {
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
}
```

I want to loop through this JSON and convert it to `list<Encounter>`

any idea how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `org.json` namespace. For your concrete example you can do:

```
ArrayList<Encounter> encounters=new ArrayList<Encounter>();
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(Result);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    JSONObject elem=(JSONObject)array.get(i);
    Encounter encounter=new Encounter();
    Encounter.Name=elem.getString("Name");
    Encounter.Age=elem.getInt("Age");
    Encounter.Address=elem.getString("Address");
    encounters.add(encounter);
}
```

Comment: Answer is 100% correct. If author has more classes with serialization/deserialization to JSON I would recommend him to look to Gson library - https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 4):

Another easier way is to use [Gson another lib](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to ease your implementation which is easier to use as compared to org.json implementation that comes with Android platform.

If you are ok with domain objects. Then you have only two lines of code to parse json...like

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourDomainObject obj2 = (YourDomainObject) gson.fromJson(jsonString,
   YourDomainObject.class);
```

and it can handle collections n all too.